# Can I update ProductName Property in runtime (during install)?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have Basic MSI project (I use InstallShield 2013 Professional). Suppose it has ProductName **DefaultProductName**.

I can build it and get setup.exe. It will appear in a list of Installed Programs in Control Panel with **DefaultProductName**  name if I install it.

Now, suppose that I want to change my ProductName from **DefaultProductName** to **NewProductName** during install, in runtime (to be more clear: I'm talking not about Upgrades, but about situation when I'm installing my product on "clean" box).

For this purpose I created New Custom Action->New Set Property and set ProductName Property to a new value **NewProductName**. It works (for example, I can see that new ProductName value appears in titles of installation dialogs, and my product appeared in Control Panel with name **NewProductName** ).

But when I'm trying to uninstall my product and moving through uninstallation dialogs, I see (in titles of dialogs) that ProductName has its default value **DefaultProductName**, not the value **NewProductName** that I set in custom action during install.  Does it mean that changes in Property value that I can apply during install will not be available during Uninstall. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because all you altered was the in-memory ProductName of the install, not any actual name in a file anywhere.

If you know before the actual install you could create a transform, a .mst file, and then start the MSI file with a command line that specifies TRANSFORMS=. You'd need an executable to do that first then launch your MSI.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer SDK in it's cryptic way implies that this is not possible.  In my experience it is not possible.  ProductName is a private property and immutable once the installation starts.   Editing the MSI or creating and applying a transform is the only way.