# Wix Instance Transform Dynamic ProductName and Id

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix3.6, instance-transform

I have a Wix wxs file where i have configured to have multiple instance using Instance Transform.

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?define WixDemoWPFApp_TargetDir=$(var.WixDemoWPFApp.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="WixSetupWPFApp" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Licence Owner"
       UpgradeCode="ae4af8f5-9287-408a-b7bd-d2fdb89a8da7">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Downgrade not allowed" />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="0" />

    <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
    <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{888F3620-F2AB-4C0B-A276-0A5AE9C0B6CB}" ProductName="WixDemo 3.7.4 Dev" />
    <Instance Id="I02" ProductCode="{01D23E62-A369-43E1-914A-FA017B1EE822}" ProductName="WixDemo 3.7.4 Test" />
    <Instance Id="I03" ProductCode="{00D804D7-0AD0-412C-805A-4D37FF74FFA3}" ProductName="WixDemo 3.7.5" />
    <Instance Id="I04" ProductCode="{6C3E5B4E-BF7D-4E7E-A62A-B7DFB750F581}" ProductName="WixDemo 3.7.6" />

   </InstanceTransforms>

   <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetupWPFApp" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
  </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>

 <SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]" />
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
    <Directory Id="WixDemo" Name="WixDemo">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WixDemo" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
 </Directory>
```

```
  <Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Component Id="WixDemoWPFApp.exe" Guid="42907ee1-2bb2-4416-8d8f-cebc2bf53f09">
    <File Id="WixDemoWPFApp.exe" Name="WixDemoWPFApp.exe" Source="$(var.WixDemoWPFApp_TargetDir)WixDemoWPFApp.exe" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="WixDemoWPFApp.exe.config" Guid="ed8a9503-2eb1-4f49-b7f3-f027f542c93f">
    <File Id="WixDemoWPFApp.exe.config" Name="WixDemoWPFApp.exe.config"
          Source="$(var.WixDemoWPFApp_TargetDir)WixDemoWPFApp.exe.config" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="WixDemoWPFApp.pdb" Guid="5bf6cd62-7bc7-42cd-839a-7b66d7e8a09a">
    <File Id="WixDemoWPFApp.pdb" Name="WixDemoWPFApp.pdb" Source="$(var.WixDemoWPFApp_TargetDir)WixDemoWPFApp.pdb" />
  </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And i install by executing the following command,

```
msiexec INSTALLLOCATION="D:\Wixtestinstance\1" /i WixSetupWPFApp.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I01"
```

1. How can i generate the Instance Dynamically through command without
   initializing inside InstanceTransform.
2. If above is not possible can the ProductName be passed dynamically
   through command without Hardcoding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance transforms must be created ahead of time. While technically nothing prevents a bootstrap from generating transforms dynamically at installation time just before invoking the MSI, multiple practical concerns do prevent this.

- An [instance transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367797.aspx) must claim an InstanceId and change the ProductCode. If you do not generate these ahead of time, you do not statically know what they are so it becomes nearly impossible to query for them later through the standard mechanisms.
- Component rules still apply, and involving instance transforms makes the implications much harder to think through. Doing so on the fly prevents creating separate components for each instance, except perhaps dynamically in the transform.
- [ProductName must be changed by a transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759170/can-i-update-productname-property-in-runtime-during-install). While this doesn't subject you to the same identification problems as generating new GUIDs, any transforms generated on the fly will not be signed. Thus using them will affect the UAC prompt, if any, shown by Windows Installer.

Of these, only the digital signature problem is likely to be insurmountable. But the potential problems covered by the other concerns are really hard to get right.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge that helped a lot, Is there a way we can change the Instance ProductName using Custom Action or by reading a xml file before the Installation Starts.

Comment: Yes, but it's subject to the third bullet point, and requires you to create (or perhaps select) a transform in your bootstrap before the installation starts. (So not a custom action, and most likely "no" is a closer approximation to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is possible to change the ARP ProductName by simply setting the `ProductName` in your Wix source file.

I'm doing this for multiple instances where I set the ProductName value according to the `INSTANCENAME` property that itself gets set as a result of a c# custom action:

```
<Property Id ="INSTANCEID" Value ="_" Secure ="yes"/>
<Property Id ="INSTANCENAME" Secure ="yes"></Property>

<InstanceTransforms Property ="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance Id ="I01" ProductCode ="*" UpgradeCode ="{GUID}" ProductName ="I01"/>
  <Instance Id ="I02" ProductCode ="*" UpgradeCode ="{GUID}" ProductName ="IO2"/>
  <Instance Id ="I03" ProductCode ="*" UpgradeCode ="{GUID}" ProductName ="IO3"/>
</InstanceTransforms>

<SetProperty Id ="ProductName" Before ="LaunchConditions" Value ="[INSTANCENAME]"></SetProperty>
```

In the Custom Action:

```
    session["INSTANCENAME"] = "_" + session["INSTANCENAME"];
```

The `ProductName ="I01"` in the `InstanceTransforms` will get replaced by the `SetProperty` call.

True, this name will not be the one displayed on the uninstall dialog - but maybe that's ok? For me the most important thing was to have a decent instance name in the ARP area.